# Are there any surviving works of Ancient Greek playwrights/poets excluding the more well known ones?

Tags: greek-language

I'm interested in the Ancient Greek plays/poetry right now. Are there any extant works from Greek poets/playwrights that aren't well known currently? This is, of course, excluding Aristophanes, Aeschylus, Euripides, Sophocles, Sappho, etc.

By well known, I mean the playwrights and poets that haven't been in mainstream literary publication or generally spoken about in the realm of literature.

Edit #1:

To be honest, I don't know why this has 2 downvotes right now because all I'm trying to do is gain more knowledge here; if my question isn't good in any way, then you should leave a comment telling me where I can improve. I'm new in town and I don't feel welcomed by this community right now.

Edit #2:

I've decided to delete this question because a) it's on hold as off-topic b) I really don't enjoy this community right now. I could have just looked on my own to find them, but I thought that it would add value to have people looking for extant Greek playwrights/poets that aren't well-known to come here. So I will probably just search on my own now. Thanks a lot for everyone who answered!

Comment: I know you've already accepted an answerr, but this question is a little poorly defined. What do you mean by "the famous ones" or "that aren't well known currently"? Famous where, well known by whom?

Comment: To be fair, I *did* leave a comment to explain what's wrong with your question (as I see it). The "put on hold" banner also explains that list/recommendation questions are off-topic for this site. I'm sorry that your first experience here had to be like this, and I hope you won't be put off from asking more questions on this site :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Exagoge* of [Ezekiel the Tragedian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezekiel_the_Tragedian), which survives in fragments, is the only extant Hellenistic-era tragedy.

Sappho is just one of many [lyric poets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Lyric_Poets), which also include Alcman, Alcaeus, Anacreon, Stesichorus, Ibycus, Simonides, Bacchylides and Pindar. The (Loeb) three-volume book [*Lyra Graeca*](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/lookupid?key=olbp71332) collects all the Ancient Greek lyric poets and also includes anonymous ancient poets.

The [*Palatine Anthology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatine_Anthology), or more broadly the *Greek Anthology* contains poems written by [dozens of poets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_Anthology#List_of_poets_to_whom_epigrams_are_attributed_in_the_Greek_Anthology). It includes poets from the ancient and Hellenistic periods, but also goes into the Christian era, so you have to check to determine their time. The anthology is also a source for some of the lyric poets, which were already given, but it also includes later poets who aren't included with the lyric poets.

Comment: *Alexandra*, attributed to [Lycophron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lycophron), would be another Hellenistic drama if the attribution were correct

Answer (score 3):

*[The Complete Greek Drama](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006AO66I)* has, in addition to the works of Aristophanes, Aeschylus, Euripides, and Sophocles, three works from [Menander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menander):

- **[Samia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samia_(play))** (translated as "The Girl From Samos")
- **[Epitrepontes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitrepontes)** (translated as "The Arbitration")
- **[Dyscolus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyskolos)**

[These works were apparently only discovered in the last century.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menander#20th-century_discoveries)